# Building code chunks in rmarkdown/Slidify with io2012 framework

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidify

I'm building a presentation using Slidify and the io2012 framework and I can't figure out how to set up the slide so that R code chunks only execute when the slide is advanced(via click or the arrow key). I am preparing a workshop and would like code chunks to remain hidden while I discuss earlier code chunks.

Elsewhere I saw that adding .build to the right of the triple hyphens accomplishes what I would like:

--- .build

OR

--- {.build}

But neither works for me.

Comment: Do you mean execute or display? Do you want something like what's discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/192)?

Comment: I mean to display. So if you wanted to pause and discuss a chunk of code (and its output) before moving on (via click or keyboard advance) to the next chunk of code. Unfortunately, that issue covers bulleted lists and text paragraphs, but not chunks of code. I've seen an answer that uses the revealjs framework, but not the io2012 framework.